# How to select an option from the non select dropdown list based on combobox using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Trying to automate one thing for my work, which was choosing one option from the dropdown list on the website below:

https://interparking-pl.my.site.com/abonament/s/?id=a0A58000000D7pZ

The Selenium automation didn't work in that case. After writing such code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_driver_path = r"C:/Users/.../Projects/chromedriver.exe"

service = Service(executable_path=chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
driver.get("https://interparking-pl.my.site.com/abonament/s/?id=a0A58000000D7pZ")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
abo_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="combobox-button-53"]')))
```

After executing I've got a message:

```
TimeoutException
```

In case of finding element by tag name or any other options, the following message pops up:

```
Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

The list is built on button tags and has a structure of lightning-basecombobox. It looks like there is no possibility to click on the dropdown list and choose the required option automatically.

Is it needed to do something different with such stuff?

What I expect is to use Selenium to choose between the options in the list.

Comment: Which element is _`//*[@id="combobox-button-53"]`_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The combobox is a *`<button>`* element.

[image: combobox]

Additionally the *id* i.e. `combobox-button-53` is dynamically generated and is bound to chage sooner/later. They may change next time you access the application afresh or even while next application startup. So can't be used in locators.

---

### Solution

To click element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48056120/7429447):

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://interparking-pl.my.site.com/abonament/s/?id=a0A58000000D7pZ")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[name='subscriptionsTypeId']"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  driver.get("https://interparking-pl.my.site.com/abonament/s/?id=a0A58000000D7pZ")
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@name='subscriptionsTypeId']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot;

[image: combobox_expanded]

Answer (score 0):

When I load the page, I get the element ID (XPATH) as following. `//*[@id="combobox-button-51"]`

Maybe the number `51` isn't always the same? In that case, try:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'combobox-button-5')]
```

Or just use `//*[@name="subscriptionsTypeId"]` , as another answer here allready mentioned.